# T-SQL is not working on DBeaver on Linux

Tags: t-sql, linux, dbeaver

I am trying to run a basic T-SQL script

```
    DECLARE @temptable TABLE(
      abilityTypeId BIGINT NOT NULL,
      companyId BIGINT NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO @temptable(abilityTypeId, companyId)
    VALUES (1, 2);

    SELECT * FROM @temptable;
```

but I get the following error:

> SQL Error [1087] [S0002]: Must declare the table variable "@temptable".
>   Must declare the table variable "@temptable".

`MERGE INTO` is also not working. 
Is it possible to get this working on Linux or do I have to use Visual Studio for this?

Comment: This works fine in SSMS, so I'd imagine DBeaver does some weird parsing. This would likely be better as a support question to the vendor.

Comment: I thought this is related to SQL engine, so maybe I just didn't figure out how to select the right one. Still, basic SQL and listing tables does work properly (MSSQL database in docker)

Comment: Yep, you should talk to DBeaver about that. Sounds like you've got a lot going on over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBeaver parses queries one by one using a statement delimiter (“;” by default) and executes them consecutively.

Try removing the empty lines and those “;”.

Check more details [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Execution).

Comment: THANKS! I CAN'T BELIEVE THIS WAS THE PROBLEM!

Comment: 3 years later, this still happens and is hard to find in a sea of "Remove the GO statement" answers that aren't applicable when you have no GO statements.  This is what fixed it for me.  Great find!